# Can't catch an Invalid Form Body error discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command to send an embed based on given JSON data, and it works, sort of.

I give the bot the data, and if it is correct, it will send it to the channel, which is perfect, exactly what I need it to do. BUT, if someone tries to put text in a link section, it will crash the bot. I tried try catch but it wont catch for some reason.

Error: `Scheme "(my string that is not a url)" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').`

```js
        try {
            let json = message.content.split(" ")
            json.shift() //get rid of the command bit, leaving the JSON
            let data = json.join(" ")
            let embedjson = new Discord.MessageEmbed(JSON.parse(data))
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedjson]}) //this works, unless it meets the problem listed above.
        } catch (error) { // >:( wont catch it
            let errorembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            console.log(error)
            .setTitle('Error!')
            .setDescription(`Something went wrong! There are a few possible issues:\n1. You tried to put text in a link option (Like putting 'hello' in the image option, or 'never gonna give you up' in the thumbnail option.)\n2. Something else\nI'll attatch the error below:`)
            .addField('Error Message', error)
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [errorembed]})
        }
```

Any suggestions as to how I can catch the error? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I believe adding `async-await` works. Test it and tell me what happens.

Comment: @MrMythical Alright, I changed `execute()` to `async execute()` and did `await message.channel.send()` and ran it again, did not work. I will try danky's solution next.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Discord.JS's client has an error event which could just log the error instead of crashing the node instance

Example:

```
client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Your code will still error, but your application will continue running. Not ideal, but a good solution if there is no other way.

You may also use `process.on('error')`, whichever floats your boat

Comment: This is not the best idea. This event is meant to handle the error properly, not exiting the process could result in it being corrupted, or having an infinite loop.

Comment: Tried it anyway, got the same error, unfortunately. Thanks though!